# Picker in NavigationView: No refresh when custom binding changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to save an enum value to UserDefaults. Therefor I created a custom binding. The UserDefault part works fine but unfortunately the value in the NavigationView does not get refreshed after changing the value with the Picker.

How can I get the chosen weather condition to be displayed?

PS: If not creating additional complexity, I would like to keep the enum Weather of type Int.

```
import SwiftUI

enum Weather: Int, CaseIterable {
    case rain
    case sun
    case clouds
}

func getWeatherText(weather: Weather) -> String {
    switch weather {
    case .rain: return "Rain"
    case .sun: return "Sun"
    case .clouds: return "Clouds"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let currentWeather = Binding<Weather>(
        get: {
            (Weather(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "weather")) ?? .sun)
        },
        set: {
            UserDefaults.standard.set($0.rawValue, forKey: "weather")
        }
    )
    
    let weathers = Weather.allCases
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Picker("Weather", selection: currentWeather) {
                    ForEach(weathers, id: \.self) { w in
                        Text(getWeatherText(weather: w)).tag(w)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to use AppStorage instead? Binding is not dynamic property, so it does not force view body rebuild. You need either State or ObservedObject.

Comment: @AppStorage was exactly what I needed. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Asperi, the solution is simple: replacing my custom Binding with @AppStorage. This is the result:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Weather: Int, CaseIterable {
    case rain
    case sun
    case clouds
}

func getWeatherText(weather: Weather) -> String {
    switch weather {
    case .rain: return "Rain"
    case .sun: return "Sun"
    case .clouds: return "Clouds"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("weather") var currentWeather: Weather = Weather.clouds
    
    let weathers = Weather.allCases
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Picker("Weather", selection: $currentWeather) {
                    ForEach(weathers, id: \.self) { w in
                        Text(getWeatherText(weather: w)).tag(w)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```